# MySQL privilege tables

Tags: mysql

I downgraded from 5.6 to 5.5 and now I can't start mysql. Log files show the following:

```
50421 12:11:10 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './mysql/proxies_priv.frm'
150421 12:11:10 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect information in file: './mysql/proxies_priv.frm'
```

I've done the following to try and resolve but no joy:

```
chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

and I've also tried the following:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=/var/lib/mysql
```

Which gives this error message:

```
Installing MySQL system tables...
150421 12:18:01 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './mysql/tables_priv.frm'
ERROR: 1033  Incorrect information in file: './mysql/tables_priv.frm'
```

I have Googled the problem for about an hour now and am still struggling. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dealt with this by first purging mysql using:
    `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-<version>`
Then I deleted everything in`/var/lib/mysql` and ran
    `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-<version>`

Comment: This follows my question but does a little more. Correct answer awarded.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had to deal with this problem as well.  Before an upgrade, it's always a good idea to backup the mysql system tables.  That way, if you need to rollback, you can get yourself back to a good state.

That being said, here we are.  Try this:

```
1. rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql/* (As suggested by user3392517)
2. mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=/var/lib/mysql
3. start mysqld
4. mysql_upgrade --force
```

Comment: mysql_install_db: [ERROR] unknown variable 'ldata=/var/lib/mysql'

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file as root or sudo

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql/proxies_priv.frm
```

Then restart MySQL.

I didn't lose any data this way.

Answer (score 0):

As with most errors that takes day or more to resolve i resorted to extreme measures:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql/*
```

Fixed the problem.

Note: Data loss did occur, but this a development server so I did not care.